# Plot multiple dataset on a same plot in R and add error values?

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe with some missing values and  I would like to plot the 'avg_rate' against 'Year' including error values (represented as ER in a sample dataframe )for all sites on a single plot? can anyone help me with this. Thank you!

```html
 Estuary                     Site Year   avg_rate        ER
1  Fortrose Estuary  Northern Flats Sediment  2018         NA       NaN
2  Fortrose Estuary  Northern Flats Sediment  2019 -0.6666667 3.7107951
3  Fortrose Estuary          Site A Sediment  2019         NA       NaN
4  Fortrose Estuary          Site B Sediment  2009         NA       NaN
5  Fortrose Estuary          Site B Sediment  2011 -2.7500000 3.5707142
6  Fortrose Estuary          Site B Sediment  2012 -1.5000000 6.7577116
7  Fortrose Estuary          Site B Sediment  2013  1.5000000 3.8729833
8  Fortrose Estuary          Site B Sediment  2015 -0.6625000 3.7063853
9  Fortrose Estuary          Site B Sediment  2016  4.0750000 2.6612967
10 Fortrose Estuary          Site B Sediment  2018 -4.5000000 0.8164966
11 Fortrose Estuary          Site B Sediment  2019  6.9000000 4.2237424
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one idea. We can use `ggplot2` to plot the data. Before plotting, we need to compute the high and low boundary of the `avg_rate` plus/minus error and store the results in two new columns.

Here are codes to pre-process the data. I removed those record with `NA` in `avg_rate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat2 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(High = avg_rate + ER, Low = avg_rate - ER) %>%
  mutate(Year = factor(Year)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(avg_rate))
```

We can plot the data using `Year` on the x-axis, `avg_rate` on the y-axis, and `facet_grid` based on `Site`. We can plot the data as point and add error bar using `geom_errorbar`

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = Year, y = avg_rate)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = High, ymin = Low)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Site)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = " Estuary                     Site Year   avg_rate        ER
1  'Fortrose Estuary'  'Northern Flats Sediment'  2018         NA       NaN
2  'Fortrose Estuary'  'Northern Flats Sediment'  2019 -0.6666667 3.7107951
3  'Fortrose Estuary'          'Site A Sediment'  2019         NA       NaN
4  'Fortrose Estuary'          'Site B Sediment'  2009         NA       NaN
5  'Fortrose Estuary'          'Site B Sediment'  2011 -2.7500000 3.5707142
6  'Fortrose Estuary'          'Site B Sediment'  2012 -1.5000000 6.7577116
7  'Fortrose Estuary'          'Site B Sediment'  2013  1.5000000 3.8729833
8  'Fortrose Estuary'          'Site B Sediment'  2015 -0.6625000 3.7063853
9  'Fortrose Estuary'          'Site B Sediment'  2016  4.0750000 2.6612967
10 'Fortrose Estuary'          'Site B Sediment'  2018 -4.5000000 0.8164966
11 'Fortrose Estuary'          'Site B Sediment'  2019  6.9000000 4.2237424",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```